# list.remove() within nested for loops

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I have two lists and want to check if elements from first list are in the second list.
If true, I want to remove the matched element from a copy of my first list.

```
my_list = [ 
    '100a',
    '100b',
    '100c'
]
    
your_list = [
    '100a_nnb',
    '100b_ub',
    '100c_AGGtb'
]

my_list_2 = my_list


for i in my_list:
    for j in your_list:
        if i in j:
            print(f'Yes, {i} is in {j}!')
            #my_list_2.remove(i)
            break
        else:
            print(f'No, {i} is not in {j}!')
```

When I leave `my_list_2.remove(i)` comment out, I got as expected:

```
Yes, 100a is in 100a_nnb!
No, 100b is not in 100a_nnb! 
Yes, 100b is in 100b_ub!
No, 100c is not in 100a_nnb!
No, 100c is not in 100b_ub!
Yes, 100c is in 100c_AGGtb!
```

When I remove # it gives me:

```
Yes, 100a is in 100a_nnb!
No, 100c is not in 100a_nnb!
No, 100c is not in 100b_ub!
Yes, 100c is in 100c_AGGtb!
```

Why is that? It seems that it skips every second list item.

Comment: `my_list_2` is not a copy of `my_list`, it is simply another reference to the same list. Use `my_list_2 = my_list.copy()` instead.

Comment: You're editing `my_list_2` and `my_list` at the same time.

Comment: `my_list` and `my_list_2` are the same object.  You're removing items from a list as you're iterating over it, which leads to all kinds of surprising behavior.

Comment: @MattDMo my_list_2 = my_list.copy() did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

[ i ]:  `my_list_2 = my_list.copy()`

[ ii ]: `my_list_2 = my_list[::]`

Notes:

by following you are just referencing my_list_2 to my_list.

```
my_list_2 = my_list
```

if you ll do check `id(my_list_2)` and `id(my_list)` you ll have the same id.

Comment: Found a very good explanation and comparison after your answer. [ii] seems to be the fastest way to copy one list to another. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line used to create the copy of the first list. Rather than creating a copy, here both variables refer to the same list in memory.

```
my_list_2 = my_list
```

As a result, you are removing the values from the original list, when you remove the values from the "copied" list.

In order to create a copy of the original list, use the copy() method

```
my_list_2 = my_list.copy()
```